# Mysql: сумма работы в месяц в часах каждым сотрудником

Tags: mysql, sql

Не удаётся написать запрос. Прошу оказать помощь. 
Имеется сортированная по возрастанию даты таблица:

```
ID         date_time
1          2019-01-01 09:00:01    /начало для ID 1 1ого числа
1          2019-01-01 18:30:00    /конец для ID 1 1ого числа
1          2019-01-02 09:00:00    /начало для ID 1 2ого числа
1          2019-01-02 18:00:01    /конец для ID 1 2ого числа
2          2019-01-03 09:10:00    /начало для ID 2 3его числа
2          2019-01-03 18:00:05    /конец для ID 2 3его числа
...        ...
```

Итог в такой форме:

```
ID       year_month         sum_hours
1          2019-01               ...   
2          2019-01               ...
```

Sum_hours - округляется до целых вверх

Comment: Как на уровне БД обеспечивается (гарантируется!) строго две записи для каждого сотрудника на один день?

Comment: В базе это никак не контролируется

Comment: Тогда не удивляйтесь, если будете получать весьма неожиданные результаты из-за неверных исходных данных в БД при отсутствии какой-либо записи или наличии повторной записи за тот же день...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе фигня вопрос

```
SELECT employee, 
       DATEFORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m') year_month, 
       CEIL(SUM(delta)/60) hours
FROM ( SELECT employee, 
              DATE(date_time) date_time, 
              TIMEDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(date_time), MAX(date_time)) delta
       FROM source
       GROUP BY employee, 
                DATE(date_time)
     ) daily
GROUP BY employee, 
         DATEFORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m')
```

Но только при условии, что ГАРАНТИРОВАНО строго две записи в день на работника.

Comment: @Mer, а Вы проверили работоспособность моего запроса и корректность отдаваемых им данных? нет, а жаль... впрочем, запрос уже поправлен.